# Ошибка при создании пулов объектов в Юнити!C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, наследование, unity3d-editor

Хочу попросить у вас помощи в решении моей проблемы.Давайте для начала расскажу о идее своей программы(если что,речь пойдёт про юнити и C#)....

Я собираюсь сделать ранер.Пул объектов,в данном случае,я буду использовать для хранения кусочков платформ,по которой бежит игрок.Но есть одна главная платформа,которая должна появиться только один раз в начале забега(игры),а затем больше никогда не появляться.Также в иерархии находятся: объект **[POOL]**,который  хранит все пулы на сцене,а также дочерний объект [POOL]а,это и есть наш пул,который ,в свою очередь,является родителем для наших платформ(Platform_Main(Clone) и Platform_Orange(Clone)).Всё это выглядит как то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот,собственно,сама **структура:**

У меня есть 3 скрипта:

**1)** Просто класс **Pool**,он ничего не наследует,содержит несколько полей и один список,который хранит префабы наших платформ(всего их 5):

```
public class Pool_2
{
    public string name;                                     // имя пула
    public bool isActive = true;                            // активен ли пул
    public GameObject poolAnchor;                           // родитель всех объектов этого пула
    public List<GameObject> pool_2 = new List<GameObject>(); //список префабов платформ
}
```

---

**2)** Основной скрипт(**PoolManager_2**),который управляет всеми пулами в сцене(пулов,пока, всего 1).Этот скрипт висит на объекте ,который никогда не удалится со сцен,через этот скрипт я закидываю в список пула префабы через инспектор,вот как выглядит инспектор этого скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот скрипт наследует **MonoBehaviour** имеет несколько методов:

**Метод 1:**

```
    public Pool_2 GetPool(string poolName)                  // этот метод возвращает значение типа Pool
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolOfPools.Count; i++)         //данный метод ищет пул объектов, по имени...
        {
            if (poolOfPools[i].name == poolName)         //...переданному в параметре как string poolName
            {
                return poolOfPools[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Метод 2:**

```
    public GameObject GeneratePoolAnchor(string poolName)     //этод метод создаёт родителя...
    {                                                         //..для пула,опираясь на имя пула
        if (GetPool(poolName).isActive)                       // если пул активен
        {
            if (GetPool(poolName).poolAnchor != null)         // если в поле poolAnchor есть значение
            {
                GameObject PoolAnchor = Instantiate(GetPool(poolName).poolAnchor);
                return PoolAnchor;
            }
            else print("No poolAnchor in Inspector: " + poolName);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Имеет пару полей**

```
    public List<Pool_2> poolOfPools = new List<Pool_2>();    // лист типа Pool
    GameObject poolsAnchor;                                  //дочерний обьект для обьектов пула
```

**Метод 3:**

```
    public List<Pool_2> poolOfPools = new List<Pool_2>();                     // лист типа Pool
    GameObject poolsAnchor;                                                  //дочерний обьект для обьектов пула

    private void Start() //просто метод Start
    {
        poolsAnchor = GameObject.Find("[POOLS]");                             //создаёт родителя для всех аулов,есои не находит его в сцене 
        if (poolsAnchor == null) poolsAnchor = new GameObject("[POOLS]");
        for (int i = 0; i < poolOfPools.Count; i++)                          //перебираем все пулы и создаём для их обьектов родителя,..
        {                                                                   //...который в свою очередь дочерний к [POOLS]
            GameObject Anchor = GeneratePoolAnchor(poolOfPools[i].name);  
            Anchor.transform.SetParent(poolsAnchor.transform);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

---

**3)** Этот скрипт(**Loader_2**) висит на определённом пуле и занимается включением и выключением объектов пула!Самое главное,что этот скрипт наследует класс **PoolManager_2**.Вначале он перебирает все объекты пула и присваивает им родителя,затем находит элемент в тэгом **"MainPlatform"** и включает его,а остальные оставляет диактивированными:

```
public class Loader_2 : PoolManager_2
{
    public Transform platformParent;               //родитель данного пула
    public string poolName = "Platforms";          // имя данного пула
    public Pool_2 platformPool;                    //ссылка на пул

    private void Start()
    {
        platformPool = GetPool(poolName);                        //берёт определённый пул по имени(смотри скрипт PoolManager_2)
        for (int i = 0; i < platformPool.pool_2.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject platform = Instantiate(platformPool.pool_2[i]) as GameObject;
            platform.transform.SetParent(platformParent);                              // устанавливает объекту определённого родителя(смотри скрипт PoolManager_2)
            if (platform.tag == "MainPlatform")
            {
                platform.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                platform.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но всё заканчивается на строчке кода: **`for (int i = 0; i < platformPool.pool_2.Count; i++)`**,на которую меня выводит ошибка

Я знаком с такой ошибкой,но обычно она решается довольно просто.Но сейчас я не могу найти никакого решения.Поэтому я решил обратиться к вам)Неужели мне придётся полностью менять структуру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я очень растянул этот вопрос,потому что он очень важен для меня..Я новичок в кодинге и мне  нужна помощь!Буду благодарен любой критики и отзывчивости!Повторюсь,я не профи..далеко не профи..И надеюсь здесь не будет море хэйта.
Спасибо)

Comment: omfg. Целая **СТАТИЩА** про банальный `Object reference not set to an instance`. Не делай так, мало того, что бестолковая, ещё и не читабельная. 2 последних скрина говорят всё.  У тебя тупо `GetPool()` выдал `null` и `platformPool.Count` забуксовал. Пользуйся `Debug.Log()`.

Comment: Спасибо!На форумах первый раз,так что решил очень подробно всё разложить)Больше так не буду!Спасибо.